# Generating RSA Key via 32 random bytes value or larger on a Android device

Tags: android, security, rsa

I am generating a random number of 32 bytes (which from Microchip PIC24F). When the Android devices receives the random 32 bytes from the PIC24F via the Android USB accessory framework, I would like to create a RSA key. Is it possible to create a public & private key through the random 32 byte?

32 bytes is relatively weak as I had some knowledge on how RSA works. Large RSA may require a lot of computing power! I am only running this on a Android mobile.

If possible I would want to know what the limitation of the computing power to calculate an secure RSA key (I do know that different phone manufacturer with different resource may vary). What is largest key I can generate with reasonable resource on the Android mobile (To the extend that the application I program will not crash/not respond/force close)

Tools Used:
Nexus One (Android 2.3.4)

Comment: So you know RSA is based on large prime numbers right?

Comment: Yeah! I know how RSA works (Complex Math Algorithm), but is it possible for Android to auto generate the keys?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to create 256 bit RSA keys? Or even want both keys of the pair to fit into 256 bits? What's your goal? Which libraries did you find and why don't you plan to use them?

Comment: @Ezylryb  well yeah thats trivial,  did you search the api?

Comment: Hm.. I should explain more so everyone can get a better understanding.

I am generating a random number of 32 bytes (which from Microchip PIC24F). When the Android devices receives the random 32 bytes from the PIC24F via the Android USB accessory framework, I would like to create a RSA key.

Is it possible to create a public & private key through the random 32 byte?

Comment: You can start any code generating an RSA pair from any source of random numbers, sure. But I'd strongly suggest to take more than 32 bytes of entropy to generate an RSA key pair, since they are typically long-lived and have more structure than random bit strings. (Oh, and you should edit your question to update the question, not hide all the info in answers.)

Comment: Android machines typically have at least a 32 bit processor with more than 250 MHz, right? That should be *plenty* for a modest 1024 bit RSA key. You only use it once for the symmetric key or the hash to sign, anyway.

Comment: N.b.: **32 bytes** (=256 bits!) of *real* entropy is **plenty** of randomness for any common cryptographic need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know very little about the Android API, but I can tell you how you would go about doing this. I doubt there is a way in the API to do this directly, but maybe this information will be enough for you to piece together what to do.

In order to generate an RSA key, you need to generate two relatively large prime numbers. I would generate two numbers with no less than 768 bits apiece.

The technique for generating these primes is to use a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) to generate 766 bit values. Basically, generate 96 bytes and throw away the upper 2 bits. Then you shift the value up by a bit, and set the lowest and highest bit so you have an odd number that's >= `2**767 + 1` (and therefor requires 768 bits to represent). Then you feed the generated number into a probabilistic prime test. First you test for divisibility by the first few odd primes, so 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and 17. Then you run a few iterations of Miller-Rabin.

If the number passes these tests, you most likely have a prime number, if it doesn't you start over and generate a new number.

Generate two such prime numbers, and you have an RSA key.

In order to generate these primes from 32 bytes of random data, you need to seed the PRNG with this data.

Personally, I would recommend getting 128 bytes of random data. You seed the PRNG with the first 64 bytes, and then every time you call it, you add one more byte of your random data to the entropy pool of your PRNG. Any cryptographically secure PRNG will have a method for doing this.